# How To Remove or Replace Words or Characters In A List

Tags: python, json, string, list

## Python Script

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = 'https://www.dunelm.com/product/caldonia-check-natural-eyelet-curtains-1000187301?defaultSkuId=30729125'

r = requests.get(url)
source_text = r.text

# Regex for extract info
product_list = re.findall('{\"delivery\"*.*false*}}}', source_text)
print(product_list, type((product_list)))

with open("json-pattern.json", "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(str(product_list))
```

The above script pulls out JSON data from the website source code and populates it within the **variable product_list** as a **LIST type**.

### Issue

The List Type (product_list) contains some **rogue characters and words** that either need **removing or replacing** in order to correctly build a Python Dictionary as below:

#### Remove or Replace

1. **['** = remove completely
2. **']** = remove completely
3. **\ \"** (backslash backslash Quote) = remove completely
4. **\ '** (backslash Single Quote) = remove completely
5. **undefined** = replace as "undefined"

*Lines 3 & 4 should not have any spaces between characters*

By removing the unwanted characters, I can then check the integrity of the JSON data by using  [codebeautify.org](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb92a39e)

Comment: try replace method for the parsed json string

Comment: Can you please provide an example as I have not have any knowledge of the mentioned technique.

Comment: its a string method `'your-string-goes-here'.replace('[', '')`, and can u post the result that you've got? it'll be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parse the Javascript data, you can use `re` module + `json.loads`. For example:

```py
import re
import json
import requests

url = "https://www.dunelm.com/product/caldonia-check-natural-eyelet-curtains-1000187301?defaultSkuId=30729125"

html_doc = requests.get(url).text

data = re.search(r"window\.D_REDUX_STATE=({.*?});", html_doc).group(1)
data = re.sub(r"undefined", '"undefined"', data)

data = json.loads(data)

# pretty print the data
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "delivery": {
        "productDeliveryMethods": {},
        "productDeliveryMethodsRequestId": null,
        "basketDeliveryMethodsByProductSkuId": {},
        "deliveryFetchFailure": false,
        "deliveryFetchRefresh": false,
        "fetchingDeliveryPromises": false
    },
    "ado": {
        "dataLoaded": false,
        "userLocation": {},
        "stores": [],
        "deliveryMethods": null
    },
    "basket": {
        "productSkusId": null,
        "preBasketQuantity": 1,
        "preXSellBasketQuantity": 1,
        "prices": null,
        "voucher": null,
        "lastAddedVoucher": null,
        "voucherErrors": [],
        "basketLoaded": false,
        "hasNoBasket": false,
        "notifications": [],
        "invalidateBasket": false,
        "deliveryCharges": null,
        "preferredDeliveryOption": null,
        "viewMode": "default",
        "isBasketLoading": false,
        "addingProduct": false,
        "stockAvailablity": null,
        "lastDeliveryOption": null,
        "selectedDeliveryCharge": null,
        "autoDeliveryOption": null,
        "basketSplit": null,
        "storeState": null,
        "storeName": null,
        "pdpBasketPopup": {
            "products": []
        },
        "isSharedBasket": false,
        "isVoucherLoading": false,
        "productUpdate": null,
        "removeProduct": false,
        "updatingBasketProducts": false
    },
    "product": {
        "productById": {
            "1000187301": {
                "id": "1000187301",
                "productUrl": "caldonia-check-natural-eyelet-curtains-1000187301",
                "name": "Caldonia Check Natural Eyelet Curtains",


...and so on.
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, thank you so much for the clear and concise solution to my problem. In particular I'd like to extend my gratitude in the way you laid out the description. Whilst I may not fully understand all techniques shown, it's a great starting point to learn. Awesome!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method for every unwanted characters:

```
"your_string".replace("[,", "")
```

I think it will work.

Comment: I need to remove/replace characters on the list type stored in the product_list variable. It's this variable that contains the rogue characters. The r.text / source_text variables contain the HTML source code which have been further manipulated to remove unwanted HTML via regex and stored in the product_list variable. When I run print(product_list.replace("['","")) is simply returns AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'